# How to modify single phase fluid/solid coupled PDEs to account for a phase change?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, diffusion, navier-stokes, convection

I have two PDEs that model both fluid and solid temperature change due to fluid flow through a packed bed. Schematic and equations here (where the f and s subscripts are for the fluid and solid respectively):

[image: PDEs]
[image: Schematic]

It seems these PDEs are limited to a **single** fluid phase (either gas or liquid) and do not account for any potential phase change (there is no phase change term). As far as I understand, this means that these equations can be used to model gas *or* liquid flow through a packed bed, but cannot be used where a phase change occurs.

My question is how could these equations be **modified** or used to account for a potential phase change occurring? Ideally rather than modelling a gas flow through a packed bed, **I would like to model a gas flow through a cold packed bed causing liquefaction of the gas**.

In addition, if there are any publications that model this I would love to see them. So far I've only found single phase models.

Link to source: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0306261921008138

Comment: What is that final term in the fluid equation?

Comment: Energy losses to the environment. Uw is the overall heat transfer losses coefficient, D and Abed are the diameter and surface area of the bed respectively. I believe this term can be assumed as zero in the ideal case. I'm adding a link to the paper in the main body in case it is required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to present the limiting solution for a much simpler case, and then you can see if you can modify it for the case you are interested in, in which there is a phase change.

At time zero, I have a bed containing a liquid, both of which are at $T_0$.  After time zero, I start flowing liquid at temperature $T_1$ through the bed at pore velocity u.  For this case, my basic starting equations are $$\epsilon \rho_fC_{pf}\left[\frac{\partial T_f}{\partial t}+u\frac{\partial T_f}{\partial x}\right]=ha_s(T_s-T_f)$$and$$(1-\epsilon) \rho_sC_{ps}\frac{\partial T_s}{\partial t}=ha_s(T_f-T_s)$$If we add these two equations together, we obtain:$$\epsilon \rho_fC_{pf}\frac{\partial T_f}{\partial t}+(1-\epsilon) \rho_sC_{ps}\frac{\partial T_s}{\partial t}+\epsilon \rho_fC_{pf}u\frac{\partial T_f}{\partial x}=0$$In our limiting situation, the liquid and solid bed temperatures will approach one another both behind- and ahead of the wave front.  Therefore, in this limiting situation, we can write:$$\epsilon \rho_fC_{pf}\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}+(1-\epsilon) \rho_sC_{ps}\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}+\epsilon \rho_fC_{pf}u\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}=0$$or$$\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}+\frac{\epsilon \rho_fC_{pf}}{\epsilon \rho_fC_{pf}+(1-\epsilon) \rho_sC_{ps}}u\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}=0$$The solution to this is a sharp wave, for which $T=T_0$ for $x>Vt$ and $T=T_1$ for $x<Vt$, where the wave velocity V is given by $$V=\frac{\epsilon \rho_fC_{pf}}{\epsilon \rho_fC_{pf}+(1-\epsilon) \rho_sC_{ps}}u$$  Of course, as expected, according to this, because of the thermal inertia of the bed, the wave front is traveling much more slowly than the fluid.

Comment: Understood. Thank you for the in depth explanation. We should also add that this is valid for T < Tsat I think, given that we don't have a phase change term yet. My initial thought is that if we were to add a phase change term, we would have to include some mechanism to make that term = 0 at everywhere except the point of phase change. So either there is a way to to do this with your equation above, or we need to have an 'if statement' of sorts in the model that says 'use the phase change equation if T=Tsat'. Does this sound right? I'm currently working my way through Transport Phenomena

Comment: Hi Chet, just checking if you're still getting notifications for this post. If you are, then I'd like to discuss this model some more if this is ok with you. I've read Bird and have taken an initial look at another paper that models flow like this. I'm now at a point that I can begin to discuss the equations above. I'll aim to post a comment tomorrow with my updated understanding of the problem

Comment: Ok I've read your solution to the limiting case, and I now understand it (!!). I can see you use the energy conservation equation to get your two starting equations. The manipulation from that point is fine. This is really (and probably still will be for the more complex cases) my biggest point of difficulty - how do you correctly take the mass/momentum/energy equations and get to these starting equations. In regards to somehow including the enthalpy and f in the energy equations, I will spend tomorrow morning looking into this. Any hints appreciated!

Comment: Initial thoughts - it seems like the assumptions made to simplify the right hand side of both equations will remain the same. The difference is that we have a dH/dt term on the left rather than a dT/dt term. Actually, the solid equation will possible be exactly the same (no changing to an enthalpy term). So really we just have to deal with the enthalpy term on the left for the fluid. We can directly sub your equation below for the enthalpy per unit mass in for H in the energy equation. Dealing with simplifying the left hand side here doesnt seem straightforward, so I'll need to think some more

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you know the pressure, then when you reach the temperature at which this is the equilibrium vapor pressure, you start forming a liquid phase.  After that, you have two phases flowing, and the enthalpy per unit mass of this mixture is $h_Lf+h_V(1-f)$, where f is the mass fraction liquid.  Rather than temperature varying in this region (for the flowing phase), f will be varying with time and position, and T will be constant (until all the vapor has condensed).

Comment: Thank you. I understand this approach, however the specifics are not clear to me yet. It seems for this approach we will not need to modify the solid PDE, only the fluid PDE will change. If this is correct, I will need a way to solve for the increase in liquid mass fraction w.r.t. position and time, meaning we will need a phase change term. What would this term look like? We can incorporate an enthalpy term using the CpT relation I presume, assuming I have temperature/pressure dependent correlations for liquid/vapour phases. However I am unsure of where the liquid fraction comes into this?

Comment: You are correct that the solid equation does not have to be modified.  I didn't include more details because I wanted to give you a chance to do the modeling on your own.  How this is handled depends on how the pressure is being handled.  Is there a momentum equation that is also being used?  If I were modeling this, I would re-derive the fluid heat balance equation and mass balance equation from scratch, just to be sure.  The enthalpy term is not CpdT;  it would involve differential in f.  And the density would also be a function of f, the terms of the specific volumes of liquid and vapor.

Comment: Ok I will attempt this. No there is no momentum equation in use that I am aware of. My understanding is currently very basic (new PhD student). I am curious to know if you would know of any textbook/resources that would go through derivations of heat/mass/momentum derivations like this? Will this involve manipulation of the Navier-Stokes equations?

Comment: And in regards to dealing with the differential in f - this is out of my knowledge range for now! So I think I should do some reading on the basic mass/momentum/energy equations and possible NS too. Would you have a roadmap for getting to the point of being able to attempt the problem I have laid out above?

Comment: For a great book, I would recommend Transport Phenomena by Bird,, Stewart, and Lightfoot.  For this particular type of system, I would recommend literature on heat transfer in porous media.  For thermodynamics fundamentals, I would recommend Fundamentals of Engineering Thermodynamics by Moran et al and Introduction to Chemical Engineering Thermodynamics by Smith and Van Ness.

Comment: Transport Phenomena seems to have suitable content to help with answering the above question. I will aim to make my way through all remotely relevant sections. Are there any sections/chapters in particular that you think are particularly relevant to this problem? By the way, I will leave this question open and return to it in a few days with a proposed solution

Comment: I would start with Chapter 11, and would work with Eqn. 11.2-3 for the enthalpy balance.  I would also need to consider the continuity equation, and would add axial dispersion to the heat transfer in a packed bed.

Comment: Thank you for the help on this. I'll aim to return here with progress towards a solution this week

Comment: Incidentally, what is the initial condition, and what is the fluid in the bed?  Also, if the axial conduction is negligible and the heat transfer coefficient between the fluid and the bed is very high, there is an interesting limiting case in which a slowly moving sharp temperature wave travels through the system in which, behind the wave front, the temperature is the inlet temperature of the fluid and ahead of the wave front, the temperature is the original temperature of the bed.

Comment: The packed bed is an energy storage system, so there are two initial condition configurations - 1) the packed bed at minimum temperature (fully charged) 2) the packed bed at ambient temperature (fully discharged). Obviously there are intermediate semi-charged situations but these are the main two. The fluid is air in this case (assumed as N2/O2 mixture). The air charges the bed in the liquid phase, and is liquefied during the discharge phase. In regards to the axial conduction, I cannot say for sure that this is negligible, however I can say that the heat transfer coefficient between fluid and

Comment: solid is very high, so yes a sharp temperature gradient moving across the bed would be a reasonable expectation. Ah I see, and in addition to knowing the temperature we would know that we have liquid phase on one side and gas phase on the other. The gradient would be sharp, however looking at other similar systems, it wouldn't be sharp enough to be assumed near zero in length

Comment: This is all correct.  Are you saying that air is being liquified?  If I'm not mistaken, you can solve for the limiting case I described analytically.  This would give you good entry into the actual problem.

Comment: Correct yes the air is liquefied by the 'charged' packed bed, which leaves the packed bed at about ambient temperature when discharged. In the second configuration, liquefied air is passed through the ambient temperature packed bed to cool it down. The air is regasified during this process. What assumptions would be made to the above PDEs to get to the limiting case? My guess would be that we can remove the solid PDE from use completely, as the solid temperature will be the same as the fluid temperature at all points. It also seems like the convection term ha(Ts-Tf) will be zero with this

Comment: assumption. Can we do something with the time/space derivatives to simplify further, given that we know there will be a sharp thermocline?

Comment: Hi Chet, I'll assume our discussion here is over. I've made some good progress in the meantime so I'm going to repost with my updated understanding in the hope that I can engage in some further discussion. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry, I haven't been visiting this thread.  I guess I just forgot about it.  I'll check out your new submission.

Comment: Thanks Chet!! Much appreciated for the discussion.

Comment: This is a very difficult and complicated problem, and the format here at stack exchange is not conducive for the discussion we need to have.  Please consider submitting this problem on PhysicsForums.com which is much more appropriate for the extended discussion and long responses.

Comment: Thanks for the advice on this Chet, and I agree - the comments section is not ideal for this. I will first rethink the structure of my post (aiming to make this problem as clear as possible), and then post on PhysicsForum.com. Are you an active member on this site?

Comment: In addition, I would like to discuss this problem with you on PhysicsForums if possible. Is there a particular forum that this questions is suited to ? The chemical Engineering forum maybe?